# MATLAB fmincon receives a vector too large

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have an optimization function that receives a large vector `x` (let's say size 50,000) of parameters. My optimization strategy involves then coping the vector `x` into the diagonal of `M`, and then do some operation with `M` which is really quick.

This is the call:

```
[T, residual]   = fmincon(@fun, init_x_params, [], [], [], [], [], [], @confuneq, options2);
```

I realize that the bottleneck of my optimization function `fun` is actually the copy of the vector `x` into the diagonal of `M`, NOT the actual operation I do afterwards with `M`. Note that I update the diagonal in a smart way by using logical indexing using the vector of indices `indices` to be updated, it cannot be done faster I believe.

This is the optimization function, which is in the scope of the main function so has access to `M`.

```
function final_error = fun(x)
    % Updates M, this is the bottleneck!!
    M(indices) = x(:);

    % DO STUFF WITH M, it's fast!
end
```

I try to solve the bottleneck by passing the entire `M` as the vector to be optimize, but of course the problem is that I cannot pass the whole matrix `M`, because it's too big (and doesn't make sense to pass ALL the matrix, as I only update the diagonal).

Is there any way to pass the diagonal of M directly to the optimization function? Or somehow pass the entire `M` but specify somehow that I only want to opimize its diagonal? Ideally I would want to use something like a 'reference' to the diagonal of `M` as a vector to optimize, but this is not possible in MATLAB I believe.

Comment: can you please share the code of your `update_diag` function?

Comment: @ammportal See updated version

Comment: @drhagen Yep, that was psudocode. Now it's actual code.

Comment: For n=50k I would probably look at solving this outside Matlab using a large-scale sparse NLP solver. Also you probably want to provide gradients (that will reduce the number of function evaluations).

Comment: @erwin-kalvelagen This makes sense. Any suggestions for solvers? Would Ceres do in this case?

Comment: I am afraid I have no experience with Ceres. Solvers I (and my clients) use a lot are CONOPT and IPOPT and somewhat less frequently KNITRO, SNOPT, MINOS and Mosek (convex only).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I found is the following:

```
%Generate an Identity vector of the same size as M (I hope M is a square matrix). You can define it earlier if it is being used multiple times.
ident_M = logical(eye(size(M, 1)));
%Change diagonal elements using logical indexing
M(ident_M) = x;
```

This took me about 0.11 seconds for a 10000 x 10000 matrix

Comment: Thanks. but that's too slow for me. I wonder if there is a way to avoid to copy the vector `x` into `M`. The problem is then how to specify to the optimization function that I want to optimize only the diagonal values.

Comment: It is not immediately clear what is the relationship between M and x. Is x a vector of the diagonal entries of M which is optimised and then passed back into M?

Comment: `x` are the values I want to optimize. I use a strategy that involves a set of multiplications so I copy it to a matrix `M` to create a system of equations that can be solved with a single matrix multiplication.

Comment: it would help if you could share the complete code of `@fun` as there might be another way to optimise your code without making the 'M' matrix

Answer (score -3):

Declare `M` as a global variable then it is shared with everything,

```
global M
```

[Declare variables as global](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html)

Comment: That doesn't work. I need to tell MATLAB what elements of M I want to optimize (only the diagonal, not the entire matrix)

Comment: :( :( Nooo global are bad! especially with names as simple as `M`. You have no way of knowing is some other function does `M=42` somewhere inside.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. They have their merits in some occations & this is one of them. My advice is not to use them everywhere just in this instance.

Comment: @DrBwts *if* you use them, for heavens shake, do not call them `M`!!! Call them something like `my_matrix_global`. This is not C, where a variable can no be created from thin air. *Any* Matlab fucntion that has an internal variable called `M` will overwrite it

Comment: I think you'll find it wasnt me who called  the  variable `M` orignally